# How to count number of feature classes in geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-database

I would like to count the number of feature classes in a geodatabase.  Some of the classes are in feature datasets as well.  I have tried get count management, but that returns the number of rows in each feature class in the GDB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run this code to get it:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = NAME OF GDB HERE

# Get stand alone FCs
fccount = len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("",""))

# Get list of Feature Datasets and loop through them
fds = arcpy.ListDatasets("","")
for fd in fds:
    oldws = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws + "\\" + fd
    fccount = fccount + len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("",""))
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws


print fccount
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: If it worked for you - please check the green check mark beside my answer!  Thanks!

Comment: +1 Also a good approach.  You may have an error with `arcpy.ListFeatureDatasets()`.  Should this be `arcpy.ListDatasets()`?

Comment: it is arcpy.ListDatasets

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed in the code now!

Answer (score 14):

The arcpy.da.Walk() method is the way to go:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
feature_classes = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="Any"):
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print "There are %s featureclasses in the workspace" % len(feature_classes)
```

The main operators here are `arcpy.da.Walk` and `len()`. `arcpy.da.Walk` simply walks through folders and subfolders and collects files of `datatype="FeatureClass"` using `feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))`.  Finally, `len()` is used to count the number of files in the `feature_classes = []` list.

**EDIT:**

From a benchmark standpoint and in the interest of science, it appears that arcpy.da.Walk method is significantly faster than the other approach.  I tested them on a FGDB with 7 FDS and 35 FC's.  Here are the results:

```
import arcpy, os, time

###########################################################################
# METHOD 1
start = time.clock()
workspace = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"
feature_classes = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Any"):
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print "There are %s featureclasses in the workspace" % len(feature_classes)

end = time.clock()
method1 = (end - start)

############################################################################
# Method 2
start = time.clock()
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"

# Get stand alone FCs
fccount = len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("",""))

# Get list of Feature Datasets and loop through them
fds = arcpy.ListDatasets("","")
for fd in fds:
    oldws = arcpy.env.workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws + "\\" + fd
    fccount = fccount + len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("",""))
    arcpy.env.workspace = oldws

print fccount

end = time.clock()
method2 = (end - start)
##########################################################################

print 'method1 completed in %s seconds; method2 completed in %s seconds' % (method1, method2)
```

[image]

Comment: That is great Aaron, I was un-aware of Arcpy.da.Walk method - but I don't have 10.1 installed yet, so I don't have access to it.  For now, I am going to have to stick with my old method, but when I upgrade - I will remember to implement your method!

Comment: arcpy.da.Walk is a huge improvement on arcpy.ListDatasets, but can still be slow if you have thousands of datasets in your GDB. Does anyone know of a faster way? Also, some weird things going on with scope - dirnames and filenames are still accessible outside the loop. It's handy, but probably shouldn't be happening!

Answer (score -2):

If you select all the feature classes in the gdb and copy them to a new location, it will give you the status of the transfer - x amount of (total) object classes transferred.  Then you just cancel the transfer.